# MulterError: Unexpected field (Upload image in formdata)

Tags: javascript, express, fetch, multipartform-data, multer

I am trying to upload a image file but get the same error on server side no matter what I try, If someone can please tell me what I am missing.

javascript:

```
        const filePicker = document.getElementById('takePhoto');
        const myFile = filePicker.files[0];
        var formData = new FormData;
        formData.append('myFile', myFile) 
        
        fetch(appURL+'onlineHelp/questionImage', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
```

Formdata posting up:

```
myFile: (binary)
```

server side

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'upload/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})
 
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

onlineHelp.post('/questionImage', upload.single("myFile"), (req, res, next)=>{
    res.send("received")
    next(
})
```

error:

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\annet\Documents\ALS homeworx API\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\annet\Documents\ALS homeworx API\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\annet\Documents\ALS homeworx API\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\annet\Documents\ALS homeworx API\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\annet\Documents\ALS homeworx API\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\annet\Documents\ALS homeworx API\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
    at SBMH.<anonymous> (C:\Users\annet\Documents\ALS homeworx API\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

I using this code to upload images or files to server nodejs.

javascript:

```
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.photo = file

    var res = await fetch('/your api', {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: formData,
    })
```

Server side:

```
   router.patch('/avatar', auth, async (req, res, next) => {
     if (req.files) {
      let photo = req.files.photo;
      if (photo.size < 3000000) {
         var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999 + 10);
         if (!photo.mv('./public/uploads/users/avatars/' + random + "_avatar." + photo.name.split('.').pop())) {
                return res.status(400).json({ "status": "error", "data": "server cann't upload" });
            }
            Users.findByIdAndUpdate(req.userId, { $set: { avatar: + random + "_avatar." + photo.name.split('.').pop(), update_in: Date.now() } }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).json({ "status": "error", "msg": err });
                }
                Users.findById(req.userId).select("-password -role -sms -sms_time -__v").exec(function (err, user) {
                    return res.status(200).json({ "status": "success", "data": user }); //user update shod
                });
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(400).json({ "status": "error", "msg": "Photo size should be maximum 3MB" });
        }
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ "status": "error", "msg": "Image not found" });
    }
   });
```

In server.js app , you should use this code:

```
    const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

    app.use(fileUpload({
      createParentPath: true
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need you present the directory in an object like

```
cb(null, { fieldName: "temp_upload" });
```

Also, just something to be aware of, if you plan on this actually being a production app and the file will need to be accessed on the website you will want to look at using an object store of some sort (s3 or other provider) simply because you more then likely have node running as a cluster ( meaning each instance uses it own thread pool and does not talk to the other ) So if a user uploads on instance 1 instance 2 will not know of the file.

Multar has an s3 plugin thats really easy to use but if your just doing point-in-time upload and reading via the node stack (uploading say an xml and then reading the file in the same process you should be ok )